# How to access second part of 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Ok im trying to loop through a 2d array to copy from one to another. I can assign the integers from the first part using:

```
array1[i] = array2[i];
```

but I cannot do the same for the other part e.g:

```
array1[][j] = array2[][j];  //this doesn't compile
```

OR

```
array1[0]j = array2[0][j];  //creates run time error
```

How can I specfically copy the second part but not the first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no 'first part' and 'second part' of a 2-dimensional array. There are `i` rows and `j` columns in an array declared `x[j][i]`.

Now for the technical side:

Java does not have true 2-dimensional arrays; it has arrays of arrays, so `x[rows][cols]` is an array `x` of `rows` arrays of `cols` elements (i.e. `x[rows]` is an array of arrays).

So when you performed `array1[i] = array2[i]`, you were copying references to the arrays of columns in the second array.

But there is no way to do the mirror image of that -- you cannot copy references to the rows but keep the column values, because the array of rows *is* `x`.

If you are looking for a "deep copy", you can do it manually with:

```
for (int row = 0; row < array1.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < array1[row].length; col++) {
        array2[row][col] = array1[row][col];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear what you mean. Bear in mind that a "2d array" is really just an array of arrays. Your first snippet of code is just copying the 'reference to the nested array' in `array2` to `array1`.

So what is the "second part" here? Are you trying to copy a "column" from one array to the other? If so, just remember: *there are no columns*. There are just arrays, and arrays of arrays, and so on. If all the "subarrays" *happen* to have the same size, that's somewhat coincidental. There's nothing to stop you from doing:

```
array1[0] = new int[100];
array1[1] = new int[5];
```

You can think of "rows" (each being an array) but what would "column 10" mean in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this class which does the job of copying arrays:
[java.util.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays a and b are the same size, this will copy b into a element by element

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        a[j][i] = b[j][i];
```

Your question doesn't really make sense though. You can't copy the "second part" of a matrix. Think of the definition:

```
int a[5][5];
```

a is an array of arrays. a[0] is not an int, it's an int array. a[0][0] however is the first element of the first array, making it an int.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said here, which are all good answers, try looping through the array via two separate for loops, one for-loop for the first dimension, and another for the second dimension. If you want all of the 'j' values in the 2nd row you can merely do

```
for(int j = 0; j < yourJDimension; j++) {
    someValue = yourArray[1][j];
}
```

This can help show you the contents of your array, and how it is structured. Also, here is a quick link that might be somewhat useful:

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html

Comment: Seems tmfset provided a similar answer to mine just a bit sooner. Still check out the link I provided to get a grasp of how a 2D array is structured, and why copying the 'second-part' isn't feasible.